# How to restart "Run Command" in KDE Plasma 5

Tags: linux, kde

When I try to launch command from "Run command" shortcut, sometimes I face this kind of situation as the following image.

I don't understand why, but the region that "Run command" bar comes out keeps showing the cropped background screen and I cannot remove it even if I finish using the shortcut.... super annoying!

I restarted KDE plasma 5 as the following link, but it didn't help.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481329/can-i-restart-the-kde-plasma-desktop-without-logging-out

I would like to know how to restart the "Run command" shortcut, and erase this annoying background screenshot.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "run command" part is called `krunner`.

The easiest way I can come up with is to kill the process (`killall krunner`/`ps x`->`kill <pid>`) and then restart it with e.g. `nohup krunner &` from a terminal.

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution!

Comment: Worked for me. `killall krunner`. I didn't even have to start it manually. The next time I pressed Alt-Space it ran again with the settings changes I had added to `~/.config/krunnerrc`